# How can I get a list of identifiers that are in the same scope of a python source file

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following source code `hello.py`:

```
1 # Print this is comment
2 def say_hello(a=None):
3     """
4     This is another comment
5     :return:
6     """
7     print("Hello, World!")
8     i = 1
9 
10 if __name__ == "__main__":
11    i = 0
12    say_hello()
```

I would like to get a dict of identifiers within each function and have the line numbers associated with each identifier. Also, I would like to have identifiers that within the global scope. In this case, the ouput has two dicts, one for each function (scope):

```
{"say_hello": 2, "a": 2, "None": 2, "i": 8}   <--- function
{"say_hello": 2, "a": 2, "__name__": 10, "i", 11, "say_hello": 12} <--- global
```

I think `ast` module should help but I'm fairly new to this module. Any pointer would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: `say_hello` is not in the scope for its function, and the global scope is a *lot* larger than that.

Comment: You can use the `locals` and `global` functions.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for the suggestion. I update my question.

Comment: @ChristianDean Can you please elaborate more on `locals` and `global`? I don't see them in `ast` api doc.

Comment: That's because they're (well, `local` is) built-in functions.

Comment: `locals` and `global` seem to return the symbol tables at the time of being invoked. I'm interested in the line number not actual the variable value. I'm not sure if `locals` and `global` are the best way to go.

Comment: What if you perform multiple operations on an  identifier?